# Apply this CSS style to gridview

Tags: css, asp.net, .net, gridview, html-table

I have this table I created manually, and I want to use a gridview to generate data instead of using a table, the table has round corners in all four corners.

```
<table border="0"  id="rounded-corner">
<thead>
<tr>

<th scope="col" class="rounded-company">#</th>
<th>RegNum</th>
<th class="rounded-q4">Actions</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
<tr>
<td class="rounded-foot-left">Summary</td>
<td>10</td>
<td  class="rounded-foot-right">some text</td>
</tr>
</tfoot>
```

Is it possible to use a gridview and still get the table look I wanted?

EDIT

This is the CSS for the table:

```
/* table */
#rounded-corner
{
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 12px;    margin: 10px;   width: 571px;
    text-align: left;   border-collapse: collapse;
}
#rounded-corner thead th.rounded-company
{
    background: #b9c9fe url('images/left.png') left -1px no-repeat;
}
#rounded-corner thead th.rounded-q4
{
    background: #b9c9fe url('images/right.png') right -1px no-repeat;
}
#rounded-corner th
{
    padding: 8px;   font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 13px;    color: #039;
    background: #b9c9fe;
}
#rounded-corner td
{
    padding: 8px;   background: #e8edff;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;     color: #669;
}
#rounded-corner tfoot td.rounded-foot-left
{
    background: #e8edff url('images/botleft.png') left bottom no-repeat;
}
#rounded-corner tfoot td.rounded-foot-right
{
    background: #e8edff url('images/botright.png') right bottom no-repeat;
}
#rounded-corner tbody tr:hover td 
{
    background: #d0dafd;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the css for the rounded corners? Have you seen this thread: http://forums.asp.net/t/1136322.aspx (top google result)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use repeater

```
<table border="0"  id="rounded-corner">
<thead>
<tr>
<th scope="col" class="rounded-company">#</th>
<th>RegNum</th>
<th class="rounded-q4">Actions</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" id="rpt_table1">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td><%# Eval("foo1")%></td>
        <td><%# Eval("foo2")%></td>
        <td><%# Eval("foo3")%></td>
        <td><asp:Button CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' OnCommand="btnedit_command" ID="btnedit" Text="Edit" /></td>
    </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</tbody>

<tfoot>
<tr>
<td class="rounded-foot-left">Summary</td>
<td>10</td>
<td  class="rounded-foot-right">some text</td>
</tr>
</tfoot>

</table>
```

on code behind .cs

```
    protected void btnedit_command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        // this is command argument value (ID) --> e.CommandArgument
    }
```

Comment: thanks for responding, does the repeater bind to data dource like the gridview?

Comment: @GovindKamalaPrakashMalviya: a GridView will be rendered as  html-table, so why should it be slower than a repeater with html-table as ItemTemplate?

Comment: @GovindKamalaPrakashMalviya how can i add the edit and delete command to the repeater. i need the repeater to got to another page with the current row information when i click edit where i can edit information.

Comment: @GovindKamalaPrakashMalviya i also want to add the same data row in the tfoot tag.

Comment: Please check I have added a button with command event so you can do edit update anything

Comment: @TimSchmelter : it is marginal because GridView have more inbuilt functionality then Repeater so render time more then Repeater.

Comment: @GovindKamalaPrakashMalviya: But if you don't need the functionality(like paging,sorting etc.), you can disable it.  So where's the performance difference? If you need it on the other side, the Repeater might not be the best choice. It'll render both as table, so on clientside is no difference. Sorry, but i'm always a little bit pedantic when people generalize assertions ;)

Comment: @GovindKamalaPrakashMalviya please i need the last row of data in the tfoot, how do i do this